# Can't get connection to Salesforce using JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, salesforce

I can't connect to Salesforce using JDBC driver.
I used driver from http://reliersoft.com/download/salesforce-jdbc-driver/
but one week ago it stopped working. Connection is failed.

I tried to use a driver from https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc
but this driver is only for read-only purposes and I need both Insert and Update actions.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

An error message I am getting is:

> rc.aX: Failed to parse detail:  START_TAG seen
>   ...... @1:752 due to: rc.aX:
>   unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen
>   ...... @1:752

**Here is a link to my project** https://github.com/aandruh/dbconnector

Comment: The error message looks not like **can't get connection**, can you provide more information?

Comment: in DriverManager class getConnection method I got Sql exception in method aDriver.driver.connect(url, info) with reason (slot_4): null

Comment: and in console I have: `INFO: Connect options: url: jdbc:sforce://test.salesforce.com
Oct 01, 2019 11:26:33 AM rc.Y a
INFO: [1 480184864 -1070976377 true true true] Communicating with SF server took 746 ms
rc.aX: Failed to parse detail:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752 due to: rc.aX: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</sf:exceptionMessage><sf:upgradeURL>... @1:752
 `

Comment: `at rc.bt.a(Unknown Source)
 at rc.bt.a(Unknown Source)
 at rc.bt.a(Unknown Source)
 at rc.bt.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(Unknown Source)
 at com.reliersoft.sforce.jdbc.f.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.reliersoft.sforce.jdbc.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.reliersoft.sforce.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Sounds like an issue you should raise on Github with the package authors

Comment: Hi @LHCHIN I added more error info and also shared project on github. Can you see it,please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a new version available, "October 2019".  Using this new version solved this problem for me.
http://reliersoft.com/download/salesforce-jdbc-driver/